# Moving an object from one point to another

Tags: java, geometry

I'm trying to get an object to move from one point to a different one in a straight line. I tried something similar a while back, but it moved until it was aligned with the axis. That code looked like this:

```
if(x < otherObject.x) x++;
else if(x > otherObject.x) x--;

if(y < otherObject.y) y++;
else if(y > otherObject.y) y--;
```

This is a highly inefficient system, and I have been looking at other ways to go about this.

But I also have to move at a specific speed which is what I have been struggling to solve. Example of coordinate movement:

```
-50,200 => 50,-100
300, 300 => 600,230
```

The goal is to get it to move in a straight line from point A to B, but it should move at an even speed. Considering this:

[image: Example]

The goal is to get it to move through the line, and the speed should make it stay on the line(some inaccuracy is acceptable, but it aligning to the X/Y axis(meaning targetX/targetY is equal to currentX/currentY should not happen).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clue us in on the logic behind the movements?

Comment: The intended movement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to forget the concept of movement from a given "source" point to a given "target" point.

Instead, think of your object at any given moment as being at a **current** point, and moving in a certain **direction** with a certain **speed**.

You will need a real number to hold the angle (in radians) representing the direction your object is moving.  If your object needs to go from source position (sx,sy) to target position (tx,ty) then the angle is computed as follows:

```
float deltaX = tx - sx;
float deltaY = ty - sy;
float angle = Math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX );
```

You will also need a real number to hold the speed at which your object is traveling.  Ideally your speed should be expressed in terms of screen units (pixels?) per second, but let's keep things simple and just let speed be expressed in terms of screen units per frame.  "Frame" simply means "whenever you get around to calculating stuff and rendering stuff".  You may be doing this as fast as you can, or you may be doing it 30 times per second, the choice is yours.

So, given all of the above parameters, to calculate your object's new position at each frame, use the following:

```
currentX += speed * Math.cos( angle );
currentY += speed * Math.sin( angle );
```

To find out whether your object has reached the "target" point, compute the distance between your object and the "target" point, and if it is small enough, consider it "there". Do not expect the current point of your object to ever become equal to the target point, that would require too much precision.

Comment: All though the movement isn't perfect, it was never intended to be either. But it moves as intended and that is all I need. Sometimes it comes a little short but it is still a good method.

Comment: it comes a little short if you have followed my advice and consider it "there" when it is a small distance from there.  What happens is that on one frame it will reach almost there, and on the next frame it will overshoot. An even better method for determining whether you have arrived at your destination is to take the current position and the previous current position and see if the target point is close to the line between these two positions.

Comment: I have a custom coordinate system so I can also check if it has reached the target grid coordinates. Very rough, but it is an improvement to just checking the coordinates. So if it overshoots but is in the grid coordinates, it is fine.

Comment: you can use bresenhams line algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to create a line - that algorithm is quite and guarantees a line without any missing points...

Comment: **Note for future viewers:** *JasperHsu* suggests `float angle = Math.atan2( deltaY, deltaX ) - Math.PI/2;`  He may be right, I can't check right now to make sure he is right.